# google map: group pins to one pin after zoom out

Tags: google-maps

Google map script has feature if zoom is 'big' it groups all pins to the one pin(circle with number of pins, here is example http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/advanced_example.html). How to call this feature on my side? I bring the javascript code which I use to display my map http://jsfiddle.net/LUuwB/ (check javascript section, it is not working there but it is example how I use it).

Thanks

Comment: just use the markerclusterer as you see it in example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a GoogleMap Features. It's thirdparty scripts devlopped by users. 
You have to go on the Wiki section http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries to download the released version, with samples and docs.

It's not hard to use.

Comment: Correct, the MarkerClusterer is a open source utility library and is not part of the core Maps API

Comment: ok, do you know how to apply  http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries to this code http://jsfiddle.net/LUuwB/ ? Thanks